# pyShipping package installation fails

Tags: python

I tried installing python package pyShipping using Anaconda prompt but it resulted in an **error Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required** so I installed Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 and retried installing pyShipping package but still, it gives me the same error.

Help me in this case!

Comment: What command did you run to produce the error? `conda install pyShipping`? `pip install pyShipping`?

Comment: I used `pip install pyShipping`

Answer (score 0):

I ran `pip install pyShipping` on Anaconda Python 3.7.0 without issue.

Try installing the 32/64-bit version of the runtime, corresponding to your Python's 32/64-bit version.

- [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 (microsoft.com)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)

To check your Python version, run `python` and look at the version string. I get `Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 08:04:48) [MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)]...` corresponding to 64-bit.